# подключение к BLE-устройству в python-приложении на Windows 11

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, kivy, bluetooth

В моём приложении на kivy есть кнопка, которая вызывает popup-окно со списком обнаруженных bluetooth-устройств. В этом окне ещё есть кнопка подключить, при нажатии на которую устанавливается сопряжение с выбранным из списка устройством. Для обычного bluetooth всё работало.
Теперь понадобилось обнаруживать bluetooth low energy устройство и подключаться к нему для принятия данных (данное устройство - это усилитель биопотенциалов, который пишет ЭЭГ и импеданс электродов).
Приложение задумывается как кроссплатформенное, под Windows и Android. Пробовала через pygatt - на windows не работает, требует физический адаптер. Ещё была попытка с помощью bleak:

```py
    async def create_btns(self):
        scanner = BleakScanner()
        await scanner.start()
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await scanner.stop()
        self.devices = scanner.discovered_devices
        await BleakScanner.stop()
        print(self.devices)
        for device in self.devices:
            btn = Button(text=str(device[1]), size_hint=(1, None), height='40dp')
            btn.bind(on_release=partial(self.select_device, name=device[1], addr=device[0]))
            self.layout1_1.add_widget(btn)
```

popup-окно отображается, но списка устройств нет, ошибка при вызове функции следующая: `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'LowBluetoothPopup.create_btns' was never awaited`. `RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`.
Может кто-то сталкивался? Заранее спасибо за ответы.